# iPhone Cellular Triangulation For Current Location

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-location

I want to get the current location of iPhone from GPS and Cellular network. Is it possible to get the location from cellular network in iPhone. Please tell me any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/getting-your-location-in-an-iphone-application

The iPhone uses wifi access points, cellular towers and gps depending on what's available and provides the information more quickly.  This all happens in the background using the Core Location framework which the tutorial above covers.

Comment: Is it possible to get the providers (Network and GPS) detail that which provider providing the location.

Comment: As far as I know any specific data about where the location came from is hidden.